# Preencher um DataTable a partir de uma lista de um tipo complexo

Tags: c#

Estou querendo criar um método que receba uma lista de uma tipo complexo qualquer `List<T>` e retorne um DataTable com todos os dados.
No meu código eu consegui chegar aqui aqui.

```
protected virtual DataTable buildDataTableFromComplexTypeList<T> ( string tableName, List<T> complexList )
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable ( tableName );
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof ( T ).GetProperties ( ); // Getting the metadata through reflection (System.Reflection)

    foreach ( PropertyInfo property in properties ) // Create DataTableColumns from the T properties
        dataTable.Columns.Add ( property.Name, property.PropertyType );

    DataRow dataRow;

    foreach ( T item in complexList )
    {
        dataRow = dataTable.NewRow ( ); // Create new DataRow with the same columns of DataTable
        dataRow[]
    }
}
```

Reparem que no primeiro `foreach` eu usei Reflection para criar as colunas, mas agora não sei como preencher com os dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da mesma maneira que você utilizou `Reflection` para recuperar as propriedades do tipo genérico, você também pode utilizar `Reflection` para recuperar o valor da propriedade para uma instância daquele tipo, ficaria assim:

```
protected virtual DataTable buildDataTableFromComplexTypeList<T>(string tableName, List<T> complexList)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(tableName);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(); // Getting the metadata through reflection (System.Reflection)

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties) // Create DataTableColumns from the T properties
    {
        var type = (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) : property.PropertyType);
        dataTable.Columns.Add(property.Name, type);
    }

    DataRow dataRow;

    foreach (T item in complexList)
    {
        dataRow = dataTable.NewRow(); // Create new DataRow with the same columns of DataTable
                                        // novas linhas
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            dataRow[property.Name] = property.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;

        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    // nova linha
    return dataTable;
}
```

Se você quiser, pode fazer o mesmo usando `Linq`

```
protected virtual DataTable buildDataTableFromComplexTypeList<T>(string tableName, List<T> complexList)
{
    DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
    PropertyInfo[] propriedades = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    tabela.Columns.AddRange(
        propriedades.Select(p => new DataColumn(p.Name, (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.PropertyType) : p.PropertyType))).ToArray()
        );

    complexList.ForEach(
        i => tabela.Rows.Add(
            propriedades.Select(p => p.GetValue(i) ?? DBNull.Value).ToArray()
            )
        );

    return tabela;
}
```

Ajustei a resposta com a colocação do @Jeferson Almeida sobre `Nullable` pois lembro que já tive problemas com isso no passado.

Fontes:
[Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)
[LINQ: IENUMERABLE TO DATATABLE](https://davefancher.com/2010/04/16/linq-ienumerable-to-datatable/)

Answer (score 4):

Além de pegar o `PropertyType` você tem que verificar se ele é `Nullable`, por isso modifiquei um pouco o seu primeiro for para fazer essa verificação e adicionar quando necessário.

Para criar as linhas basta criar um array na mesma sequências que criou as colunas do `DataTable` e depois adicionar esse array com o seguinte comando `dataTable.Rows.Add(array)`

```
protected virtual DataTable buildDataTableFromComplexTypeList<T>(string tableName, List<T> complexList)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(tableName);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(); 

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        var type = (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) : property.PropertyType);
        dataTable.Columns.Add(property.Name, type );

    }

    foreach (T item in complexList)
    {
        var values = new object[properties.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(item, null);
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: Não entendi a necessidade de verificar se é `Nullable`

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Por exemplo, se seu campo for um `int` ou um `datetime` e vc tentar setar um valor nulo neles vai dá erro, pois esses campos por padrão, não aceitam valores nulos a não ser que sejam declarados como `Nullable` e quando vc verifica somente o tipo não informa se aquele campo aceita isso

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida bem observado sobre `Nullable` (ajustei minha resposta, espero que não se importe), porém para preencher o que é `null` no `DataRow` tem que usar `DBNull.Value` senão irá acusar erro.

Comment: Ok, entendi no código do Xará @Mateus. É que no seu exemplo a variável `var type` não é utilizada.
Valeu pela observação sobre a possibilidade de ser nullable.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva foi mal, esqueci de usar ela, vou ajustar meu codigo