# IsGenericType, GetGenericTypeDefinition e Nullable.GetUnderlyingType

Tags: c#, .net, genéricos, reflexão, nullable

Em um trecho de código me foi sugerido o uso desses três membros afim de verificar se as propriedades de um objeto são `Nullable`.

```
p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition ( ) == typeof( Nullable<> ) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType ( p.PropertyType ) : p.PropertyType
```

Eu não consegui encontrar uma explicação satisfatória sobre esses membros, `IsGenericType, GetGenericTypeDefinition e Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`, não entendi muito bem o que eles retornam. A documentação não foi suficiente para meu entendimento.

[Pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/185008/37326) onde foi sugerida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem [informações sobre reflexão aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154462/101).

Os tipos em código rodando no .NET possuem [metadados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101) diversos sobre sua composição emitidos pelo compilador.

Você consegue acessar essas dados partindo do método [`GetType()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_Object_GetType) ou operador [`typeof`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que retornará um objeto [`Type`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Uma das propriedades deste objeto é `IsGenericType` que como o próprio nome indica é um booleano dizendo se o tipo que você está verificando é [genérico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) ou não. Se ele não for genérico é óbvio que ele não é um tipo anulável já que todo tipo anulável precisa estar contido dentro do objeto [`Nullable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) e encerra devido ao [*short-circuit*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154056/101).

Se ele for genérico passa para a próxima onde ele verifica especificamente se o método `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` retorna o mesmo tipo que o `Nullable`, indicando que [o tipo é anulável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125827/101).

Se não for um tipo anulável então você pode pegar o tipo deste objeto que ele é o que deseja.

Mas se o tipo é anulável você deve pegar o tipo que está dentro do objeto `Nullable`. Isto é feito com o método [`GetUnderlyingType()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Nullable_GetUnderlyingType_System_Type_). Podemos traduzir o *underlying* como "por baixo dos panos". Então o que será pego é o tipo genérico do `Nullable`.

Bem simplificadamente o tipo `Nullable` é algo assim:

```
struct Nullable<T> when T : struct {
    bool HasValue; //determina se esse objeto é nulo ou não
    T value; //é o objeto que lhe interessa de fato
    //tem mais um monte de coisa aqui, inclusive o método GetUnderlyingType()
}
```

O que você deseja colocar no `DataTable` é esse `value` aí. Você tem que configurar o `DataTable` com o tipo dele e não com o tipo `Nullable`.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(typeof(Nullable).Name);
        WriteLine(typeof(Nullable<>).Name);
        int? nInt = 0;
        decimal? nDecimal = 0M;
        List<int> lInt = new List<int>();
        int xInt = 1;
        string xString = "";
        decimal xDecimal = 2M;
        Dictionary<string, int> dStingInt = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        PrintObject<int?>(nInt);
        PrintObject<decimal?>(nDecimal);
        PrintObject<List<int>>(lInt);
        PrintObject<int>(xInt);
        PrintObject<string>(xString);
        PrintObject<decimal>(xDecimal);
        PrintObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(dStingInt);
    }
    private static void PrintObject<T>(T obj) {
        var type = typeof(T); 
        var generic = type.IsGenericType;
        var nullable = generic && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
        WriteLine($"{type.Name} - {type.IsGenericType} - {(generic ? type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Name : (""))} - {(nullable ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type).Name : (""))} - {type.Name}\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/br1wNT). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8fteBK). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/NullableTypes%2Ccs).

Comment: Deixa eu aplicar algumas situações para tentar entender melhor. `IsGenericType` retorna true se o tipo que ele está analizando for algo como `int?`, `decimal?`, `List<int>`, etc. E retorna false case o tipo seja `int`, `string`, `decimal`, etc.
Já `GetGenericTypeDefinition` retorna o tipo genérico "base" usado para criar o tipo final, ou seja, para `Dictionary<string, int>` ele retorna `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. Comparando com C++, eu dou o tipo genérico e ele me devolve o template. Seria isso?

Comment: Qual a diferença entre `typeof(Nullable)` e `typeof(Nullable<>)`. Encontrei alguns exemplos que usam a primeira forma.

Comment: A primeira está correta. A segunda está quase correta, na verdade o nome sofre um *mangling* e internamente o nome é diferente do que você conhece. C++ não tem mecanismo prontos que faça isto, então não dá para comparar. Note que tudo isto são apenas informações simples. Sem usar `<>` pega o tipo sem considerar a genericidade, e com `<>` pega o tipo genérico, como pode ser observado no que eu fiz na resposta.

Comment: Entendido.
Na verdade quando eu citei C++, eu apenas quis exemplificar como seria se C++ tivesse algo parecido.